# Call to a javascript function

Tags: javascript

I'm using https://github.com/LPology/Simple-Ajax-Uploader/ to upload some images via ajax.

Using the following script, it would upload successfully.

```
var uploader = new ss.SimpleUpload({
    multipart: true,
    button: 'browse-photos',
    url: '//' + server + '/api/main/member/album/uploadimage',
    name: 'uploadfile',
    responseType: 'json',
    allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'],
    accept: 'image/*',
    maxSize: 2000,
    hoverClass: 'btn-hover',
    focusClass: 'active',
    disabledClass: 'disabled',
    multiple: true,
    onSubmit: function(filename, ext){
        // loading image here
        var id = filename.replace(/ /g,"_").replace(/\./g,"_");
        var li = $('<li id="'+ id +'" class="photo-upload-item"><div style="background: url(\'/main/images/ajax-loader2.gif\') #eee no-repeat center;box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #aeaeae; overflow: hidden;width:150px; height: 150px"></div></li>');

        wrapper.append( li );
        return true;
    },
    onSizeError: function() {
        alert('Files may not exceed 2Mb.');
    },
    onExtError: function() {
        alert('Invalid file type.');
    },
    onComplete: function(file, response, btn) {
        var id = file.replace(/ /g,"_").replace(/\./g,"_");
        cntr = $('#' + id);

        img = '';
        if (!response) {
            alert('Unable to upload file');
        }

        if (response.success === true) {
            cntr.empty().attr({
                'data-file': response.file,
                'data-number': count
            });

            ++count;
            img += '<div class="photo-upload-cont" data-count="'+count+'">';

            //foto
            img += '<span class="photos">';
            img += '<img src="' + response.thumb +'">';
            img += '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="delete_image(this, \''+ response.file +'\')"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>';
            img += '</span>';

            //description
            img += '<span class="description" style="float: left;">';
            img += '<textarea placeholder="Your caption here" class="photocomment"></textarea>';
            img += '</span>';
            img += '<span class="clear"></span>';
            img += '</div>';
            cntr.append( $(img) );

            $(".photos-container").sortable({
                // items: '.photo-upload-item',
                placeholder:'sortable-placeholder',
                cursor:'move',
                helper: 'clone',
                // helper:'clone'
                sort: function(event, ui) {
                    var $target = $(event.target);
                    if (!/html|body/i.test($target.offsetParent()[0].tagName)) {
                        var top = event.pageY - $target.offsetParent().offset().top - (ui.helper.outerHeight(true) / 2);
                        ui.helper.css({'top' : top + 'px'});
                    }
                },
                stop: function (event, ui) {
                    ui.item.removeClass('dragging');
                    $(this).find('li').each(function(i){
                        var index = i+1;
                        $(this).attr('data-number', index);
                    });
                }
            });

        } else {
            if (response.msg)  {
                alert(response.msg);
            } else {
                alert('Unable to upload file');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is, I need to call the `uploader` again, through a  modal box in another page. The `uploader` script above is in the body (already called). Are there any ways, I could call the `uploader` by (maybe) calling it like this in modal box?

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="form-group">
    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file btn-block" id="browse-photos" onclick="uploader()">Choose File</span>
</div>
```

Complete script:

```
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="col-xs-12 p0">
    <div class="img-add">
        <form class="form" name="postForm" action="" method="POST" id="formPostAddImage" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <!-- TODO drag and drop order photo-->
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <ul class="photos-container col-xs-12 p0" style="position: inherit;"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file btn-block" id="browse-photos" onclick="uploader()">Choose File</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- your another code here -->
        </form> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Above

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: can you post a little more code which shows your attempt?

Comment: take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener

Comment: Post your code from edit page.